# Changing the default icon in a Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I need to change the icon in the application I am working on. But simply browsing for other icons from the project property tab -> *Application* -> *Icon*, it is not getting the icons stored on the desktop..

What is the right way of doing it?

Comment: Are you changing the property of the form, or the application?

Comment: What icons are stored in your desktop? Make sure its in ico format.

Comment: how to convert jpg into ico format??

Comment: If you're looking for icons that are already in the correct format to use in your application, see the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142203/does-net-have-icon-collections

Answer (score 106):

The icons you are seeing on desktop is not a icon file. They are either executable files **.exe** or shortcuts of any application **.lnk**. So can only set icon which have **.ico** extension.

> **Go to Project Menu -> Your_Project_Name Properties ->
> Application TAB -> Resources -> Icon**

browse for your Icon, remember it must have **.ico** extension

**You can make your icon in Visual Studio**

> **Go to Project Menu -> Add New Item ->
> Icon File**

Answer (score 38):

Add your icon as a Resource (Project > yourprojectname Properties > Resources > Pick "Icons from dropdown > Add Resource (or choose Add Existing File from dropdown if you already have the .ico)

Then:

`this.Icon = Properties.Resources.youriconname;`

Comment: This is the best answer among all. This even works with a published single EXE file

Comment: Perfect. In VB.Net I used Icon = My.Resources.youriconname

Comment: This should be the top answer. The only that keeps the icon in the exe file.

Comment: I couldn't get any of the other answers to work. but This worked great. This answer is simple and direct and should be at the top !!!

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me in a .NET 6.0 Windows Forms project, using Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 27):

The Icon displayed in the Taskbar and Windowtitle is that of the main Form. By changing its Icon you also set the Icon shown in the Taskbar, when already [included in your *.resx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/339stzf7.aspx):

```
System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = 
    new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MyForm));
this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("statusnormal.Icon")));
```

or, by directly reading from your Resources:

```
this.Icon = new Icon("Resources/statusnormal.ico");
```

If you cannot immediately find the code of the `Form`, search your whole project (`CTRL+SHIFT+F`) for the shown Window-Title (presuming that the text is static)

Answer (score 11):

You can change the app icon under project properties. Individual form icons under form properties.

Answer (score 7):

Once the icon is in a .ICO format in visual studio I use

```
//This uses the file u give it to make an icon. 

Icon icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(String);//pulls icon from .ico and makes it then icon object.

//Assign icon to the icon property of the form

this.Icon = icon;
```

so in short

```
Icon icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon("FILE/Path");

this.Icon = icon;
```

Works everytime.

Comment: `Works everytime.` wrong, doesn't work if the application is published as a single exe file

Answer (score 7):

I added the .ico file to my project, setting the Build Action to **Embedded Resource**. I specified the path to that file as the project's icon in the project settings, and then I used the code below in the form's constructor to share it. This way, I don't need to maintain a resources file anywhere with copies of the icon. All I need to do to update it is to replace the file.

```
var exe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var iconStream = exe.GetManifestResourceStream("Namespace.IconName.ico");
if (iconStream != null) Icon = new Icon(iconStream);
```

Answer (score 6):

Put the following line in the constructor of your Form:

```cs
Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the way to set the same icon to all forms without having to change one by one.
This is what I coded in my applications.

```
FormUtils.SetDefaultIcon();
```

Here a full example ready to use.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        //Here it is.
        FormUtils.SetDefaultIcon();

        Application.Run(new Form());
    }
}
```

Here is the class FormUtils:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static class FormUtils
{
    public static void SetDefaultIcon()
    {
        var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(EntryAssemblyInfo.ExecutablePath);
        typeof(Form)
            .GetField("defaultIcon", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static)
            .SetValue(null, icon);
    }
}
```

And here the class EntryAssemblyInfo. This is truncated for this example. It is my custom coded class taken from System.Winforms.Application.

```
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;

public static class EntryAssemblyInfo
{
    private static string _executablePath;

    public static string ExecutablePath
    {
        get
        {
            if (_executablePath == null)
            {
                PermissionSet permissionSets = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
                permissionSets.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
                permissionSets.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode));
                permissionSets.Assert();

                string uriString = null;
                var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

                if (entryAssembly == null)
                    uriString = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
                else
                    uriString = entryAssembly.CodeBase;

                PermissionSet.RevertAssert();

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uriString))
                    throw new Exception("Can not Get EntryAssembly or Process MainModule FileName");
                else
                {
                    var uri = new Uri(uriString);
                    if (uri.IsFile)
                        _executablePath = string.Concat(uri.LocalPath, Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Fragment));
                    else
                        _executablePath = uri.ToString();
                }
            }

            return _executablePath;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

On the solution explorer, right click on the project title and select the 'Properties' on the context menu to open the 'Project Property' form. In the 'Application' tab, on the 'Resources' group box there is a entry field where you can select the icon file you want for your application.

Comment: Just to add that in addition to that, he would have to change the icon of his forms as well

Answer (score 1):

I found that the easiest way is:

1. Add an Icon file into your WinForms project.
2. Change the icon files' build action into *Embedded Resource*
3. In the Main Form Load function:

   Icon = LoadIcon("< the file name of that icon file >");

Answer (score 1):

Try this, e.g. in the form constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  string imagePath = @"" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "path-for-icon";
  using (var stream = File.OpenRead(imagePath))
  {
     this.Icon = new Icon(stream);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I follow Csmotor answer to set icon in my project but I need one more step to convert from `Icon` to `ImageSource`.

I shared for whom concerned.

```
this.Icon = ExportXML.Properties.Resources.IDR_MAINFRAME.ToImageSource();

public static class Helper{
        public static ImageSource ToImageSource(this Icon icon)
        {
            ImageSource imageSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                icon.Handle,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            return imageSource;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The **Simplest** solution is here: If you are using Visual Studio, from the `Solution Explorer`, right click on your project file. Choose `Properties`. Select `Icon and manifest` then Browse your `.ico` file.

Answer (score 0):

Select your project properties from Project Tab
Then Application->Resource->Icon And Manifest->change the default icon

This works in Visual studio 2019 finely
Note:Only files with .ico format can be added as icon

Answer (score 0):

select Main form -> properties -> Windows style -> icon -> browse your ico

`this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));`