# Change Windows Forms icon

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I created a small application in C # with Windows Forms and VS2015, I currently have a slight worry:

I would like on my desktop appears my executable (.exe) with my custom icon. I put one; I just changed the logo to make it more adequate. I can change the icon, in my file, executable understands the new logo but when I want to move it to the desktop, it re-appears to me the old logo, while I deleted it from my pc

I thought it had to be temporarily stored in a folder in VS2015 but I do not know where and do not know why.

Could you help me on this?

Thank you !

Comment: does this thread help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489928/how-to-set-desktop-icon-to-c-sharp-windows-form

Comment: No, because in my case, i put a new icon in the project properties, and on my desktop appears the old ...

Comment: try clearing the icon cache

Comment: Thanks a lot @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ ! :)