# Is there a recommended icon set for Windows 7 programs?

Tags: windows, windows-7, icons

I'm currently putting the final touches on my program and need an icon set that follows the Windows 7 user experience guidelines. Microsoft has released an [icon set](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/03/27/windows-phone-7-series-icon-pack.aspx) for Windows Phone 7. Is there any such icon set for Windows 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are icons included with Visual Studio that are licensed for inclusion in Windows applications (much like the icons for Windows Phone 7 are now included with Expression Blend). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142203/does-net-have-icon-collections/4142304#4142304) on how to get at them.

Otherwise, no, there are no standard icons for Windows applications. Not that it would be a bad idea, but no such set currently exists. Many developers copy the icons used by Windows itself and Microsoft Office applications in an attempt to provide a consistent, familiar UI, but you have to be careful when doing this without proper licensing.

The easiest way is to use some of the other icons sets available online. Many are free and are of outstanding quality. The other answers to the question linked to above provide some suggested sources.

Answer (score 0):

you can start here: [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx)

Comment: I have already read it, but was wondering if an icon set is publicly available online.

Answer (score 0):

The [SHGetStockIconInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762205%28VS.85%29.aspx) function will provide you with some of the icons at runtime (UAC shield changed color between Vista and 7 etc)