# Setting up WPF treeview triggers to show different images on expand

Tags: wpf, triggers, treeview, datatrigger, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a wpf tree view that displays nodes of various types with corresponding images such as folder images.  Initially, the tree and its nodes with corresponding images display as expected.  However when a node is expanded, the expectation is that the image for the expanded node should swap to an expanded image.  I'm trying to use `HierarchicalDataTemplate` triggers to set this up.

**Should the triggers be set up differently?**

The tree looks something like:

```
(Folder Image) Solutions (SolutionsViewModel)
--(Solution Image) Solution 1 (Solution)
--(Solution Image) Solution 2 (Solution)
(Folder Image) Conventions (ConventionsViewModel)
```

The xaml of the main nodes in the tree view (the theme is empty):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Theme.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SolutionsViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image x:Name="nodeImg" Width="16" Height="16" Source="pack://siteOfOrigin:,,,/Resources/FolderClosed.bmp"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="nodeImg" Property="Source" Value="pack://siteOfOrigin:,,,/Resources//FolderOpen.bmp"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sol:Solution}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image x:Name="treeImg" Width="16" Height="16" Source="pack://siteOfOrigin:,,,/Resources/SolutionClosed.bmp"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="treeImg" Property="Source" Value="pack://siteOfOrigin:,,,/Resources//SolutionOpen.bmp"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ConventionsViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image x:Name="nodeImg" Width="16" Height="16" Source="pack://siteOfOrigin:,,,/Resources/FolderClosed.bmp"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="nodeImg" Property="Source" Value="pack://siteOfOrigin:,,,/Resources//FolderOpen.bmp"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <ObjectDataProvider 
    ObjectType="{x:Type vm:TreeViewModel}"
    MethodName="CreateDefaultTree"
    />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView Name="solutionsModel" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392007/how-can-i-change-the-treeview-icon-into-a-folder-icon-in-wpf) might be relevant.

As in my answer to the question I linked I would do the triggering in the image via `RelativeSource` binding, you can refactor that into a style so you do not have all that redundant code.

Possibly you could work with DynamicResources to provide the two images to every Image-control, or you could sub-class `Image` or create a UserControl which provides properties.

---

The DynamicResource method:

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ExpandingImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource Icon_Closed}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}, Path=IsExpanded}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource Icon_Open}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

```
<!-- Example usage -->
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type obj:Employee}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Style="{StaticResource ExpandingImageStyle}">
            <Image.Resources>
                <BitmapImage x:Key="Icon_Closed" UriSource="Images/FolderClosed.ico"/>
                <BitmapImage x:Key="Icon_Open" UriSource="Images/FolderOpen.ico"/>
            </Image.Resources>
        </Image>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 5):

For completeness, the original setup with the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` triggers just needed to use a `RelativeSource` binding (as indicated by HB's answer), such as:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type svm:SolutionsViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}">
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStackPanelStyle}">
        <Image x:Name="nodeImg" Style="{StaticResource IconImageStyleSmall}" Source="{StaticResource Icon_FolderClosed}" />
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemTextStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}, Path=IsExpanded}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="nodeImg" Property="Source" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource Icon_FolderOpen}, Mode=OneTime}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Below is an example image with different images on expand in the `TreeView`:

[image: Tree view with images]