# Change DataGrid cell content/template on row select

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

The behavior I am aiming for is: I have a data grid with a single column. It is bound to a list of items which contain various information about a person. When not selected, the row simply displays the person's name. When the row is selected (i.e. clicked on), I was to show more information about the person.

My first attempt was to use a DataGridTemplateColumn where the CellTemplate is a ContentControl. The style of the ContentControl is determined by the status of the selected row.

My style:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NotSelectedTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=DataContext.PatientName.FormattedName, Mode=OneWay, BindsDirectlyToSource=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedTemplate">
    <TextBlock Height="60" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=DataContext.PatientName.FormattedName, Mode=OneWay, BindsDirectlyToSource=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
   </DataTemplate>

<Style x:Key="SelectableContentStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource NotSelectedTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

My datagrid columns:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource SelectableContentStyle}" />
             </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

This approach *works*, however the binding in each DataTemplate is pretty ugly. I am relatively inexperienced at WPF, so I'm sure there must be a much better way to implement this.

Basically,
1) Is there a better way to acheive this behavior?
2) Is there a better way to bind to the DataTemplate so I am not chasing RelativeSources any time I want to access a property?

Comment: That is pretty much how i would do it.

Comment: I see. The bindings in the DateTemplates are very ugly though. Considering I will have 5+ textblock/properies bindings, I was hoping there was a cleaner way do the binding within each DataTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a template selector for the `ContentTemplateProperty` which takes two templates as properties and has one boolean property to switch between them.

The bad news is that the base class (`DataTemplateSelector`) is not a dependency object and as such does not support a binding for your flag property. In those cases i work around that by adding a `Config` property that holds an instance of a custom class which you then can make a sub-class of `DependencyObject` and define dependency properties there.
This of course will bloat your code again, and bindings will have limitations because, informally speaking, the binding scopes break.

---

Another option might be to reference the two templates in the `SelectableContentStyle` via `DynamicResource`, that way you just need to write that `DataTrigger` switch once and merely define the two templates in the resources within the individual `DataTemplates`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5797323/546730) for an example.