# Standard icons for buttons that change WinForms ListView.View

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, icons, windows-explorer

I have a custom control containing a `ListView` control, which displays files in the manner of Windows Explorer. I'd like to add the same buttons Windows Explorer has for changing the `ListView.View` (i.e. the buttons for "details", "list", "small icon", etc), but can't locate the icons (I've been searching through `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\VS2010ImageLibrary\1033\VS2010ImageLibrary.zip`). Does anyone know where I can find these? Thanks.

(I suspect there isn't a pre-made control with the Vista/Win7 style drop-down button with slider and buttons for each view, but if there is, that'd be great!)

Comment: There are no standard buttons for that.  Nor does Explorer use ListView.  You'll need to make your own.

Comment: **Related:** [Does .NET have icon collections?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4142203/1497596)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that those icons are embedded in one of the windows assemblies (I don't know which one, but I would guess Shell32 or something).  In order to get them, you'll need to extract them from the assembly.

There are many options for extracting them, you could use a tool such as [this](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html) or use the [ExtractIconEx API](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.extracticon).

If you [google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=extracting+icons+from+dll&aq=2&oq=extracting+icons+from+&sugexp=chrome,mod=2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), you'll see lots of other options as well.

NOTE: I'm not sure about licensing for these icons, so depending on how/where you're using them, I'd recommend researching what is acceptable use of these icons.

Comment: Thanks very much. I guess if they're not very accessible, there may be a licensing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fatcow hosting icons at http://www.fatcow.com/free-icons have all the icons you need. There are also icons for presenting listview's view property and good thing is that it is free for all kinds of use including commercial.