# ASP.Net MVC Document Type Icon

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In ASP.Net MVC is there a library function or something that I can call to retrieve a file's document type icon? I'm talking about the icons you see in window's file explorer, like for pdf, word, excel, ect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get common file type icons in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616718/how-do-i-get-common-file-type-icons-in-c)

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701263/get-the-icon-for-a-given-extension

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio 2010, it installs a folder at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\VS2010ImageLibrary\1033\VS2010ImageLibrary.zip`, which contains many common icons.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142203/does-net-have-icon-collections) for more information.

If you don't have VS 2010, you can extract the icons you want by following the instructions on [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404308(v=vs.110).aspx).